# How can I fix these errors in plsql code?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE user_man_sys(
    user_id      INT NOT NULL,
    user_name NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    user_password INT    ,
    created_date DATE    ,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypackage AS
    PROCEDURE add_user(
                                      u_id              user_man_sys.user_id%type,
                                      u_name           user_man_sys.user_name%type,
                                      u_password      user_man_sys.user_password%type,
                                      u_created_data user_man_sys.created_date%type);
   PROCEDURE Checkuserlogin(new_username  user_man_sys.user_name%type,
                                              new_password  user_man_sys.user_password%type   )
  PROCEDURE rest_password ( r_password  user_man_sys.user_password%type)             
END mypackage ;
/



CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mypackage AS
    PROCEDURE add_user(
                                        u_id              user_man_sys.user_id%type,
                                      u_name           user_man_sys.user_name%type,
                                      u_password      user_man_sys.user_password%type,
                                      u_created_data user_man_sys.created_date%type)
                                       IS
       BEGIN
          INSERT INTO user_man_sys(user_id,user_name ,user_password  ,created_date)
            VALUES(u_id, u_name,u_password,u_created_data );
      END add_user;
   PROCEDURE Checkuserlogin(new_usernameuser_man_sys.user_name%type,
                                             new_password  user_man_sys.user_password%type)
          IS 
       BEGIN
          SET NOCOUNT ON

          SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM  user_man_sysWHERE user_id=new_username AND user_password=new_password)
          THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
           ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
   END Checkuserlogin;
PROCEDURE   rest_password ( r_password  user_man_sys.user_password%type,r_user user_man_sys.user_name%type)
  IS
BEGIN
   UPDATE credentials
      SET password = r_password               -- use as parameter in procedure
    WHERE username = r_user;

   -- or you can include "and id = p_id" in where clause
   IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0
   THEN
      COMMIT;
      RETURN 'Password Reset Successful.';
   ELSE
      RETURN 'Password Reset Failed. Invalid User Name';
   END IF;
END rest_password  ;



   
end mypackage;
/
```

My code performes these tasks :
1)procedure to create user.
2)procedure to reset password.
3)procedure to check login cardinals.
I want to repair this error in this code if i ceate a package or the body of the package shows a mistacke (the package or the body of the the package are configured with translation errors)
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few errors.

Table is created with no problems:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE user_man_sys
  2  (
  3     user_id         INT NOT NULL,
  4     user_name       NVARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
  5     user_password   INT,
  6     created_date    DATE,
  7     PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
  8  );

Table created.
```

This is a table that's getting updated; I don't have it, so I'm creating a *dummy* one, just to make package body compile:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE credentials
  2  (
  3     password   VARCHAR2 (10),
  4     username   VARCHAR2 (20)
  5  );

Table created.
```

Package specification: you're missing semi-colons (as terminators); description of procedures in body must match the ones in specification (`rest_password` is wrong, then; also, as it can't `return` anything (it is not a function, I added an `out` parameter):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypackage
  2  AS
  3     PROCEDURE add_user (u_id            user_man_sys.user_id%TYPE,
  4                         u_name          user_man_sys.user_name%TYPE,
  5                         u_password      user_man_sys.user_password%TYPE,
  6                         u_created_data  user_man_sys.created_date%TYPE);
  7
  8     PROCEDURE Checkuserlogin (new_username  user_man_sys.user_name%TYPE,
  9                               new_password  user_man_sys.user_password%TYPE);
 10
 11     PROCEDURE rest_password (r_password      user_man_sys.user_password%TYPE,
 12                              r_user          user_man_sys.user_name%TYPE,
 13                              par_result  OUT VARCHAR2);
 14  END mypackage;
 15  /

Package created.
```

Package body: typos (missing spaces); `set` belongs to SQL*Plus, not PL/SQL procedures; `Checkuserlogin`'s `select` statement requires an `into` clause and valid datatype (`bit` isn't):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mypackage
  2  AS
  3     PROCEDURE add_user (u_id            user_man_sys.user_id%TYPE,
  4                         u_name          user_man_sys.user_name%TYPE,
  5                         u_password      user_man_sys.user_password%TYPE,
  6                         u_created_data  user_man_sys.created_date%TYPE)
  7     IS
  8     BEGIN
  9        INSERT INTO user_man_sys (user_id,
 10                                  user_name,
 11                                  user_password,
 12                                  created_date)
 13             VALUES (u_id,
 14                     u_name,
 15                     u_password,
 16                     u_created_data);
 17     END add_user;
 18
 19     PROCEDURE Checkuserlogin (new_username  user_man_sys.user_name%TYPE,
 20                               new_password  user_man_sys.user_password%TYPE)
 21     IS
 22        l_val  NUMBER;
 23     BEGIN
 24        --SET NOCOUNT ON
 25
 26        SELECT CASE
 27                  WHEN EXISTS
 28                          (SELECT NULL
 29                             FROM user_man_sys
 30                            WHERE     user_id = new_username
 31                                  AND user_password = new_password)
 32                  THEN
 33                     1
 34                  ELSE
 35                     0
 36               END
 37          INTO l_val
 38          FROM DUAL;
 39     END Checkuserlogin;
 40
 41     PROCEDURE rest_password (r_password      user_man_sys.user_password%TYPE,
 42                              r_user          user_man_sys.user_name%TYPE,
 43                              par_result  OUT VARCHAR2)
 44     IS
 45     BEGIN
 46        UPDATE credentials
 47           SET password = r_password            -- use as parameter in procedure
 48         WHERE username = r_user;
 49
 50        -- or you can include "and id = p_id" in where clause
 51        IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0
 52        THEN
 53           COMMIT;
 54           par_result := 'Password Reset Successful.';
 55        ELSE
 56           par_result := 'Password Reset Failed. Invalid User Name';
 57        END IF;
 58     END rest_password;
 59  END mypackage;
 60  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

That's it, as far as *compilation* problems is concerned. Does your code do what you planned, I wouldn't know. Test it yourself.